# Having trouble in understanding what subset of a poset means.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

I am having a problem to visualise a subset of a poset. Let $S = \{a,b,c\}$. Then $\mathcal{P}(S) = \{\{\},\{a\}, \{b\},\{c\},\{a,b\},\{a,c\},\{b,c\},\{a,b,c\} \}$. Now if I impose $\subseteq$ on $\mathcal{P}(S)$, then the partial order relation is $ R = \{(\{\},\{a\}),(\{\},\{b\}),(\{a\},\{a,b\})(\{c\},\{a,b,c\}),(\{a,b\},\{a,b,c\}), \cdots\}$. Now, the partial order set or poset is $(S, R)$. I am not understanding what should be the subset of a poset like this. Can any kind-hearted one help me understanding this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "subset of a poset" is just what a subset always is: Take however many or few elements of the poset you like, put them into a set and give them a name. That's a subset of the poset!

Note that this is an entirely different thing than "the poset of subsets of $S$" which is what you're describing. This is shorthand for "the poset whose elements are all the subsets of $S$, ordered by set inclusion".

Apart from the name, your example of the poset of subsets of $\{a,b,c\}$ looks *almost* right -- the actual poset is $(\mathcal P(S),R)$, not $(S,R)$. It is not clear to me from the question that there's any understanding you actually lack.

Comment: Hi sir. I know the partial order relation as examplified in $R$. But I am meddling things as you said. Then can you clarify me what the poset is for $S =\{a,b,c\}$?

Comment: @user36790: The poset of subsets of $S=\{a,b,c\}$ is exactly what you describe in the question -- except it should be $(\mathcal P(S),R)$ instead of $(S,R)$.

Comment: Then, sir , what will you call $(S,R)$? Also, I request you earnestly to please give me an example of subset of the poset; it only contains two elements: $\mathcal{P}(S) \quad \& \quad S$, I suppose? Please, please, give me an example of subset.

Comment: @user36790: Your highness, I don't call $(S,R)$ anything. $(\mathcal P(S),R)$ is an _ordered pair_; it means that $\mathcal P(S)$ is the _set_ we're talking about and $R$ is the _partial order_ on that set. The poset has 8 _elements_ -- every subset of $S$ is an element of the poset. Thus there are $2^8=256$ subsets _of_ the poset, One of them would be, for example, $\{\{a,b\},\{a,c\},\varnothing\}$. (But these subsets are not important; I think you must be misunderstanding something by focusing on them).